# Spork causing undefined method error in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, spork

I have a standard Rails 3.2 app with some weird behavior going on.

I can run `rspec spec/` without spork running and all tests pass no problem.

Then I fire up spork and run the specs again. This time, every test that touches one of my mailers will fail with the same error:

```
Failures:

  1) InvitationsController GET accept with non-matching token should redirect to the root path
     Failure/Error: let!(:invitation) { Factory :invitation }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `invite' for InvitationMailer:Class
     # ./app/models/invitation.rb:29:in `send_email'
     # ./spec/controllers/invitations_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Then, just to make it all a little weirder, I can run individual directories or specs, with or without spork running, and everything passes no problem. e.g `rspec spec/mailers` or `rspec spec/models`.

Here is the method which I am being told is undefined:

```
class InvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: APP_CONFIG[:default_from]

  def invite(invitation)
    @invitation = invitation

    mail(to: @invitation.recipient_email, subject: "the subject")
  end
end
```

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: @duckufuzz, did you find solution?

Comment: Nope. I'm planning on taking spork out of the app soon. I love spork when it works but I find I just can't trust it most of the time.

Comment: Without the factory and test code it is hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time tweaking Spork, I think it is possible to fix this.

For some reason, Spork is not loading the InvitationMailer file. So, the one thing you can do is require it within the `Spork.each_run do` block.

Also, here is the process I have used to diagnose Spork issues:

1. Move everything in the spec helper except for `require 'spork'` to inside the `Spork.prefork do` block. Make sure there are no errors. Use `time` to see how fast.
2. Move some code into the `Spork.each_run do` block.
3. Check to see if the the error happens. Use `time` to see how fast the tests run.
4. See if the error occurs. If so, then move some code back to `pre_fork`.
5. Keep moving stuff around until you figure out what needs to be in the `prefork` block and how much faster it runs.

This process was explained in this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork).